# Center div using margin 0 auto

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, margin

I learned several examples on the internet, but obviously i'm missing something, because my markup is not working.

AFAIK this coude should work, but it doesn't. Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <body style="background: #cdc7ae" class=" ms-backgroundImage" spellcheck="false">           
        <div style="margin: 20px auto;">Hello!</div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <div style="margin: 20px auto; width:450px; /*desired width*/">Hello!</div> you need to add width as well

Comment: Not sure why you updated the question. The answers are still correct, you need to define a width or its default is `100%` you could just `text-align:center;`

Comment: @Ruddy you're right, i should use text-align. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky No problem. I will put up an answer, what way it may help other people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a width on the `<div>`, e.g.

```
<div style="margin: 20px auto; width: 200px">Hello!</div>
```

Comment: Yep. Applying a background on each element shows the problem without width

Answer (score 2):

So turns out you are looking for:

```
<div style="margin: 20px auto; text-align: center;">Hello!</div>
```

Without setting a `div` width it will be `100%`, so we can use `text-align: center` to get the text in the center. No need to move the whole `div` by setting a width in this case.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/us3hf/)

Comment: I'l mark as answer Taimur's answer, but i'l also vote up your's. Tnx

Answer (score -1):

You must give a **width** to your div.  Otherwise, it assume `100%` width and `margin:auto` does not take effect.